# 401 AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED - telegram

Tags: python, telegram, auth

[10:45:10] Поймали вот такую ошибку - [401 AUTH_KEY_UNREGISTERED]: The key is not registered in the system (caused by "contacts.ResolveUsername")

Получаю вот такую ошибку при работе с pyrogram. Код не имеет значения, поэтому его здесь не будет.

Есть пару проблем/ограничений:

1. У меня нет другого доступа к аккаунту, кроме как через файл session.
2. У меня на компьютере такой проблемы не возникает, все работает. Но если я пересылаю файл session на другой пк и запускаю его там, то он не работает и выдает эту ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

в ошибке же написано - ключ не зарегестрирован в системе, значит надо "сгенерировать" новый my_account.session